# How to "Pause" observing in callback of a MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion, callback, mutation-observers

For example, I want to write some codes in `.my-codes`.

```
<head>
<script class="my-codes">
    var ob = new MutationObserver(
        function (mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(
                mutation => {
                    mutation.addedNodes.forEach(
                        node => {
                            if(node.nodeName === "DIV"){
                                // Without this browser may crush for infinite recursion
                                this.disconnect(); 
                                let innerNode = document.createElement("div");
                                innerNode.className = "inner-div";
                                console.log("Insert div to a ." + node.className);
                                node.appendChild(innerNode);
                                // Method below does not exist
                                /* this.reconnect(); */ 
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            );
        }
    );
    ob.observe(document, {childList:true, subtree:true});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div1">
        <script>
            let asyncDiv = document.createElement("div");
            asyncDiv.className = "div3";
            setTimeout(()=>document.body.appendChild(asyncDiv), 10);
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
</body>
```

Expected Result (if something like `this.reconnect();` exists) :

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="inner-div"></div>
</div>
<div class="div2">
    <div class="inner-div"></div>
</div>
<div class="div3">
    <div class="inner-div"></div>
</div>
```

Actual Result (the observation completely stopped after the first insertion):

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="inner-div"></div>
</div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
```

**Is there a reliable way to implement the `this.reconnect();` function?**

(It will be better not to mess with global variables, codes below is not considered a reliable way since the callback function need to capture global variable)

```
var target = document;
var config = {childList:true, subtree:true};
var ob = new MutationObserver(
    function(mut, observer){
        this.disconnect();
        /* mess with DOM */
        observer.observe(target, config);
    }
)
ob.observe(target, config);
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems the right way to use kind of *global variables* . But they dont need to be global:

```
function observe(target,config){
  target =target|| document;
  config = config||{childList:true, subtree:true};
  var ob = new MutationObserver(function(mut, observer){
      ob.disconnect();
    /* mess with DOM */
      ob.observe(target, config);
  });
 ob.observe(target, config);
}

observe();
```

This can be extended to provide a more general way of observing:

```
function customObserver(target,config,callback){
 this.target =target|| document;
 this.config = config||{childList:true, subtree:true};
 var that=this;
 this.ob = new MutationObserver(function(mut,observer){
    callback.call(that,mut,observer);
 });
 }

customObserver.prototype={
  connect:function(){
    this.ob.observe(this.target,this.config);
  },
 disconnect:function(){ this.ob.disconnect()}
};
```

So one can do:

```
var observer=new customObserver(document,false,function(observer,mutations){
  observer.disconnect();
  //som DOM changes
 observer.connect();
});
observer.connect();
```

Comment: In fact I'm the one that tries to `reconnect`, I'm using the `setMutationHandler` from `https://greasyfork.org/scripts/12228/code/setMutationHandler.js`.  I didn't find a way to get access to the original target & config. Is it possible to `reconnect` without modifying the original `setMutationHandler.js`?